# List of strings to list of words

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, data-science

So, I am trying to figure out the best way to go about taking a list of strings and converting it into a list of words. I also want to strip all the punctuation from the string. My thought process is to do the following:

1. Make one big string of the list of strings using the .join() method and list comprehension/map.
2. Use the string translate method to remove the punctuation.
3. Use the split method to split the gigantic string back into a list.

This seems like a large number of steps to go from a list of strings to a list of words. Does anyone have a more concise method or can make suggestions to my process? The end-goal is to pass the list of strings into the counter class to find the most common word(s).

Below are the current output and the desired output.

```
list_of_strings = ['This is string one.', 'This is string two.', 'This is string three.'] # current output
```

```
list_of_words = ['This', 'is', 'string', 'one', 'This', 'is', 'string', 'two', 'This', 'is', 'string', 'three'] # desired output
```

Comment: Are three very simple steps really "a large number of steps"? This seems entirely reasonable to me.

Comment: Try this: `list_of_words = ''.join(s for s in list_of_strings).replace('.', ' ').split()`

Comment: @Harshil that does produce the desired result. The only thing I can see is that the only punctuation being replaced is the '.' Definitely something to iterate on and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Accept any of the correct answers if the issue is resolved. @user3727648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this (`rstrip` the string from `.` rather than a `strip` and split around white-spaces, join the lists obtained after splitting via `sum`):

```
>>> sum([i.rstrip(".").split(" ") for i in list_of_strings], [])
['This', 'is', 'string', 'one', 'This', 'is', 'string', 'two', 'This', 'is', 'string', 'three']
```

Answer (score 0):

First for-loop extract one line at a time. ex:-

```
list_of_strings[0] = 'This is string one';
```

Then `word = line.split()`, here `split()` splits line into words by delimiter=(space)

Second for-loop appends or adds all the split words to list_of_words array.

```py
list_of_strings = ['This is string one.', 'This is string two.', 'This is string three.']
list_of_words = list()

for line in list_of_strings:
    word = line.split()

    for i in word:
        list_of_words.append(i)

print(list_of_words)
```

Comment: u can use trim() to remove '.' or u can just take index upto length-1 to avoid including upto '.'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
list_of_words = [j.strip('.') for i in list_of_strings for j in i.split()]
```